# Touch and Tap gestures recognition simultaneously with UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to handle Touch and Tap gestures recognition simultaneously with UIGestureRecognizer?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what kind of recognizer you mean with touch, but i suppose you mean something like pan. But yes, it is possible, simply by creating multiple gesturecognizers. Example:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

I'm assuming you know the basics of gesturerecognizers. If not, i'll be happy to give you a link to a tutorial and help you with any additional questions.
However, if they both use the same kind of gesture (like pan and swipe, or a single and double tap recognizer), you will need to use *requiresgesturerecognizertofail*.

Comment: Thanks, this topic becomes more complex for me then I expected to implement with gesturerecognizer... I've implemented it by using just touchesBegins/Ends/... staff.

Comment: Actually, it's a whole lot easier than that. You simply attach a gesturerecognizer to a view, and it will call your selector when the event fires. The touchesbegan/ended delegate methods require a lot more work. Edit: here you go, this is what i used to get to know them: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/

Answer (score 0):

You can use touch methods and gestures as long as you set cancelsTouchesInView to NO on the gesture.